# Hibernate and antlr.RecognitionException not found

Tags: hibernate, noclassdeffounderror

I want to learn Hibernate. I found some tutorial, but I have one issue with launching the project. This is my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.1.jre8</version>

    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

This is my class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Session session = HibernateUtilWapro.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    Query q = session.createQuery("From Employee ");

    List<Employee> resultList = q.list();
    System.out.println("num of employess:" + resultList.size());
    for (Artykul next : resultList) {
        System.out.println("next employee: " + next);
    }
}
```

I run it in Eclipse Oxygen as a Java application, but I am getting the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/RecognitionException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator(ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)

What dependency do it need? Thanks a lot for help

Comment: I too have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add the following dependency. It solved my issue.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
 <artifactId>antlr-complete</artifactId>
 <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing to add the depencies of hibernate-core:

Add in [pom.xml](/questions/tagged/pom.xml) :

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.30.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Then refresh dependencies and restart App.