# I get this error while connecting database in spring boot

Tags: java

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

```
Mon May 18 12:40:03 IST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
antlr/RecognitionException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/RecognitionException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator(ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:716)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:816)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:113)
    at com.allstate.SpringCURDApp.DAO.EmployeeDAOHibernateImp.findAll(EmployeeDAOHibernateImp.java:41)
    at com.allstate.SpringCURDApp.DAO.EmployeeDAOHibernateImp$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2672bdf3.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:7
```

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError probably you forgot to add a dependency, or haven't got that library in your classpath

Comment: Does that solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433222/hibernate-and-antlr-recognitionexception-not-found ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a dependency in your project.
So add following in your pom.xml if you are using maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

It will resolve your dependency problem.

Comment: i have already added this dependencies in pom file, but still i m not getting same error